# "Call a taxi" and "Call for a taxi" is the same?

Tags: sentence-construction, phrase-usage

I want to make a question sentence like the below 
"Is calling a taxi is the only way to take a taxi here? (Or from here?)"

- and wonder if 'calling for a taxi" would mean same as "calling a taxi".
- Also, would it have any slight difference if I use 'from here' instead of just 'here' at the end of the sentence?

Comment: The specific example about 'call for' is helpful to understtand its meaning. + Umm.. "Do I need to call a taxi here?" already contains the meaning of 'the only way to take a taxi is to call it' ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While both expressions are idiomatic, **call a taxi** is far more common, as illustrated in the Google Books Ngram Viewer below.

The expression **call for** is generally used in the sense of **required**. To say that this **calls for a taxi** means that a taxi will be required - as opposed to a bus or a bicycle for example.

If you needed to make a phone call to get a taxi, you might also say: **I need to call for a taxi**, meaning to make a call for a taxi. But the use of **for** is optional here.

Note that your sentence is repetitive and awkward: People would not say: **Is calling a taxi is the only way to take a taxi here?**. Rather just: **Do we need/have to call a taxi (here)?** Or, **Should we call a taxi (here)?**

The use of **from here** implies from this point, as though you have walked a certain distance and now require a taxi to continue your journey. Just **here** simply means to your location.

https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=call+a+taxi%